# Alert Dialog comes before another Intent activity finished

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-alertdialog

In the following code spinet , I want that dialog comes only after activity (Intent) i finished its work. I searched a lot but couldn't figure out how to do this. :(
Currently, dialog popped in between when Intent I is doing work .

Do anyone know how to allow dialog to wait until Intent i finished its work

Thanks

```
                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, KeyFrame.class);

                        i.putExtra("keyFrame", filename1+"#"+duration);
                        //Log.e("Mobicom: Video Name" + MainActivity.videoDir + video_filename, MainActivity.videoDir + video_filename);

                        startActivity(i);



                        MainActivity.this.showDialog(MainActivity.GENRE_PREFERENCE_OPTION);
```

Here is the full code.

```
 @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            switch (id) {
            case VIDEO_OPTION_DIALOG:           
                Builder optionDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                optionDialog.setTitle("Options");
                optionDialog.setItems(
                    new String[] { "Option1", "Option2", "Delete", "Cancel"}, 
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            String video_filename = MainActivity.mSelectedVideoFilename;
                            String filename1 = MainActivity.videoDir + video_filename;

                            switch (which) {
                            case OPTION_PREVIEW_ID:
                                // preview
                                startActivity(new Intent().setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(MainActivity.videoDir + video_filename)), "video/*"));
                                break;
                            case OPTION_PREVIEW_WITH_RECOM_ID:



                                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, KeyFrame.class);

                                i.putExtra("keyFrame", filename1+"#"+duration);
                                //Log.e("Mobicom: Video Name" + MainActivity.videoDir + video_filename, MainActivity.videoDir + video_filename);

                                startActivity(i);



                                MainActivity.this.showDialog(MainActivity.GENRE_PREFERENCE_OPTION);


                                //finish();
                                break;

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, KeyFrame.class);

i.putExtra("keyFrame", filename1+"#"+duration);
//Log.e("Mobicom: Video Name" + MainActivity.videoDir + video_filename, MainActivity.videoDir + video_filename);

startActivity(i);



MainActivity.this.showDialog(MainActivity.GENRE_PREFERENCE_OPTION);
```

you are starting new activity and then showing dialog so its obvious that it will be shown in transaction. also this is not a good practice as it cane lead to leaked intent.
you can start your activity on response to your dialog so after finishing your current activities work n purpose your next activity will be started.

if this dialog is for next activity then start it in next activity.